# How to use UIStepper

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I am trying to work with `UIStepper` to increment or decrement an integer,
but both "-"  and "+" increase the integer!  How can I recognize the "+" and "-" button?

In the `UIStepper` header file there are two `UIButton`s:

```
UIButton *_plusButton;
UIButton *_minusButton;
```

for example :

```
- (IBAction)changeValue:(id)sender 
{        
    UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper *) sender;

    stepper.maximumValue = 10;
    stepper.minimumValue = 0;      
    if (stepper)
    {
        integer++;
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",integer]];
     }
     else
     { 
         integer--;
         [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",integer]];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You should ignore the ivars.  They will not help you.

The `UIStepper` has a `value` property that you can query to figure out what the current value is.  So your method could simply be:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
  double value = [sender value];

  [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];
}
```

Comment: thanks but I've got this error :
`Multiple methods named 'value' found` and `Initializing 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'NSString *'`

Comment: @Mc.Lover make sure the variable is correctly typed or casted.  You'll need to make sure it's explicitly a `UIStepper*`.  Declaring it as an `id` is what's causing the warning.

Comment: You can do this [(UIStepper*)sender value] if you are sure that sender is always a UIStepper.

Comment: Still probably a good idea to preface with:

if ([sender class] == [UIStepper class])

Comment: @RembrandtQ.Einstein I would personally use `-[sender isKindOfClass:[UIStepper class]]`. You'd never know which UIStepper class it actually is, it could be a cluster class, which is a subclass of UIStepper.

Comment: stepper.wraps = false for disable autoRepeat  and

Int(stepper.incrementButton.state.rawValue) == 1 // + button clicked Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

UIStepper returns Double value, for swift version do this:

```
@IBAction func stepperValue(sender: UIStepper) {
    print("the stepper value is :\(sender.value)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the outlet of UIStepper:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper;
```

In viewDidLoad Method:

```
self.stepper.wraps=YES;
```

if YES, value wraps from min <-> max. default = NO

```
 self.stepper.autorepeat=YES;
```

if YES, press & hold repeatedly alters value. default = YES

Set the initial value to 0.

```
NSUInteger value= self.stepper.value;

self.label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lu",(unsigned long)value];
```

Set the Maximum value

```
self.stepper.maximumValue=50;
```

Take the action of UIStepper:

```
- (IBAction)valueDidChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
//Whenever the stepper value increase and decrease the sender.value fetch the curent value of stepper
        NSUInteger value= sender.value;
        self.label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lu",value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think such an error is not possible in Xcode 11.2. But if you have found this topic in search "How to use stepper" here is an answer:

1). Create a stepper on the storyboard, control drag it as always. It should create a referencing outlet.

2). You need a function that is connected to this particular stepper, whose argument is sender: UIStepper. It should be something like

`@IBAction func stepperValueChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {}`

3). Now write what should happen when the function is executed (each time you press the stepper). For explanation lets use label. Control drag him as we always do. The below is in the function, this line is executed when the stepper is hit.

`valueLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description`

And that's it.

P.S.
Stepper has "special abilities", namely:

-> Autorepeat means - holding stepper increases counter fast. True/false
-> Wrap - values are in "circle". Dropping below smallest value will give the biggest. Exceeding the biggest - you drop to the lowest. The stepper is somehow looped.
-> isContinuous. Better to make it always true.

These properties i can change by choosing them in Attributes inspector.

Also for the reference:
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/stepper-ios-tutorial

Answer (score -7):

Try

```
    stepper.maximumValue = 10.0;
    stepper.minimumValue = 0.0;
```