# UIStepper to control volume instead of UiSlider

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I am developing a simple music player in xcode and want to try using stepper instead of slider for volume.I have tried using 'valuechanged' and passing it to volume but in vain.

```
-(void)adjustVolume
{
    if (audioPlayer != nil)
    {
         audioPlayer.volume = volumeControl.value;//volume control is (IBAction) for stepper
    }
}
```

help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you have try this , i don't check this code exactly :

```
  audioPlayer.volume= ourStepper.value;
```

and UIStepper changevalue for this method:

```
- (IBAction)stepperValueChanged:(id)sender
{
     double stepperValue = ourStepper.value;
     audioPlayer.volume= stepperValue;
}
```

For more detail for `UIStepper`:

[UIStepper-tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/uistepper-tutorial-example-sample-cod/)

[How to used UIStepper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779443/how-to-use-uistepper)

[UIStepper Changevalue Snippet](http://www.ioscreator.com/change-values-with-uistepper/)

Comment: in ViewDidLoad method, the Xcode intelligence will not show volume as an object of AVPlayer and display error:-'Property volume not found as an object of AVPlayer'