# Adding a Stepper

Tags: objective-c, uistepper

Hi I am trying to add a stepper to my app but got this error:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {    
      IBOutlet UILabel *NrOfQuestLabel;}
-(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender;
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender:{ double value = [sender value];
[NrOfQuestLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];
 }
```

Error in .m: !Expected identifier
             !"sender" used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

Any help?

Comment: Xcode is just the IDE and this question is about a syntax error in Objective-C code so the "objective-c" tag is better.  It looks like you're missing a closing brace `}` in the .h file after the declaration of `NrOfQuestLabel`.

Comment: @Anna, sorry it was there I missed when copy/past... the error is in the .M file :(

Comment: `(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender:` to `-(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779443/how-to-use-uistepper?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless its another typo, you have an extra colon in xour code right after sender:

```
-(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender:{ 
    double value = [sender value];
    [NrOfQuestLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];
 }
```

should be

```
-(IBAction)NrofQuestChange:(UIStepper *)sender{
    double value = [sender value];
    [NrOfQuestLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];
 }
```

Thats why the compiler can't decide whether sender is a variable or part of the method name.